# Nginx: Redirect all but one

Tags: nginx

I have the following http config:

```
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           example.com;

  # Necessary for Let's Encrypt Domain Name ownership validation
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /home/vagrant/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
  }

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I would like `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename` to serve `/home/vagrant/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename` while every other http request should be redirected to https.

I thought Nginx would process rules in their order, if matches, uses it, otherwise continues. But apparently not. How can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `root /home/vagrant;`?

Comment: It absolutely should be `/home/vagrant`. `nginx` adds the `location` onto whatever the `root` path is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should move that redirect to be in the "/" block:

```
location / {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

They do process in order, but yours is *outside* of any location block, so likely is taking precedence.

Comment: This was the solution in my case. Thank you so very much!

Comment: This is the right answer, as well as removing the unnecessary `.../.well-known/acme-challenge/` from the `root`.

Answer (score 4):

According to nginx, putting `root xxx` in a location block is a [pitfall](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

After some struggle, here's my working config:

```
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           example.com;
  root /vagrant/www/current/public;

  # Necessary for Let's Encrypt Domain Name ownership validation
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    try_files $uri /dev/null =404;
  }
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the config that worked for me as well.   Have been trying to figure out how to complete the let's encrypt challenge but still redirect everything else to https on ngins.

Comment: Justification for downvote: The pitfall is to repeat the same root for every block. For this question, it is entirely appropriate (and elegant!) to put a root in a location block. Your solution is making things needlessly complex.